# Windows 7: the product key you entered does not appear to be a valid windows 7 product key

Tags: windows-7, activation, oem

While bulk activating OEM Windows 7 PRO x64 products (we re-image the PCs every three months or so), I always have issues with a couple of machines.

The issue I'm facing now is that it reports "the product key you entered does not appear to be a valid windows 7 product key", even though this is the key that is printed right on the sticker of the PC.

When this happened previously, I just chose 'Activate by telephone' and everything was fine. However, that option is greyed out now. What I've tried:

- running 'slui.exe 4' in an elevated command prompt, this just opens up the option dialog, in which 'activate by telephone' is greyed out.
- 'slui.exe 04', 'slui.exe 5', etc.
- net stop sppsvc, and then executing the commands "CD %windir%\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SoftwareProtectionPlatform | REN tokens.dat tokens.bar |net start sppsvc | slui.exe"

This is all not working. Can I call Microsoft directly/other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

running the following commands worked:

- slmgr /ipk "product key"
- slmgr /ato